# How to flash the background of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a function that flashes the website every time you call it.

My approach was like this:

```js
function flashRed() {
  document.body.style.animation = "redflash 0.06s 2 alternate ease-out";
}

function flashGreen() {
  document.body.style.animation = "greenflash 0.06s 2 alternate ease-out"
}
```

```css
@keyframes redflash {
  to {
    background-color: #FFCDD2;
  }
}
@keyframes greenflash {
  to {
    background-color: #C8E6C9;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="RED" onclick="flashRed()">
<input type="button" value="GREEN" onclick="flashGreen()">
```

But this way I can only make it flash it once, as the animation attribute is set the first time or changes.

How can I change my code, or use a different approach to make it flash as often as i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add and remove the class with an timeout...

```js
function flashRed() {
  document.body.classList.add('red')
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.classList.remove('red')
  }, 100)

}

function flashGreen() {
  document.body.classList.add('green')
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.classList.remove('green')
  }, 100)
}
```

```css
@keyframes redflash {
  to {
    background-color: #FFCDD2;
  }
}
@keyframes greenflash {
  to {
    background-color: #C8E6C9;
  }
}
.red {
  animation: redflash 0.06s 2 alternate ease-out;
}
.green {
  animation: greenflash 0.06s 2 alternate ease-out;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="RED" onclick="flashRed()" id="red">
<input type="button" value="GREEN" onclick="flashGreen()" id="green">
```

Comment: @juwi Haha! But, when you get a taste of it, you'll love it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear `.animation` once each function gets executed. Having said that, also, by clearing them you would  not be able to see the effect so you'll have to use `setTimeOut`

```
 function flashRed() {
    setTimeout(function(){  document.body.style.animation = "redflash 0.06s 2 alternate ease-out"; }, 100);

      document.body.style.animation="";
    }

function flashGreen() {
setTimeout(function(){  document.body.style.animation = "greenflash 0.06s 2 alternate ease-out" }, 100);
  document.body.style.animation = "";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7t1m517t/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using keyframe animations, simply add/remove the classes with timeouts.

Here's a function where you can pass in the class, and the number of times you want to flash:

https://jsfiddle.net/1vzzaqvw/2/

```
function flash(cssClass, flashNum, delay, total) {
    if(typeof total === 'undefined') total = 1;
  if(typeof delay === 'undefined') delay = 500;
  document.body.classList.add(cssClass);
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.classList.remove(cssClass);
    if(total < flashNum) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            flash(cssClass, flashNum, delay, ++total);
        },delay);
    }
  },delay);
}
```

Then you can call it, i.e `flash('red', 3)`, which would flash the red class 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the animation can only be run once because the `animation` property has been set. To allow for the same animation to be run multiple times in a row you can clear the `animation` property after the animation has completed.

There are a few ways to do this, one simple way is with a `window.setTimeout` function.

```js
function flashRed() {
  document.body.style.animation = "redflash 0.6s 2 alternate ease-out";
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.style.animation = "";
  }, 0600);
}

function flashGreen() {
  document.body.style.animation = "greenflash 0.6s 2 alternate ease-out";
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.style.animation = "";
  }, 0600);
}
```

```css
@keyframes redflash {
  to {
    background-color: #FFCDD2;
  }
}
@keyframes greenflash {
  to {
    background-color: #C8E6C9;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="RED" onclick="flashRed()">
<input type="button" value="GREEN" onclick="flashGreen()">
```